# Vercel is making my .env public., The production env can access my secret key even when I did not provide it

Tags: reactjs, deployment, environment-variables, vercel

I have a react app deployed to vercel using vercel --prod
I also have a .env file which is in the gitignore, but still when I see the production it already took the .env even though I have not added anything in the vercel directly, How do I fix this and how is this happening? The official documentation is not detailed and does not explain about this behavior.